# Virtualbox Ubuntu Server, host shared folder... where is it?

Tags: virtualbox, mount, ubuntu-16.04

I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious or if this doesn't work the way I think it should, but I cannot... find... the shared folder.

I have the Guest Additions installed.

[image]

I have rebooted.  Is there something more I need to do?  I'm *assuming* that "auto-mount: yes" means that I don't need to mount the drive.  Where is it?  It's not in /downloads, not in /mnt or /media.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I installed `virtualbox-guest-dkms` and after a reboot, without running any commands, there was a new folder in `/media/` called `sf_downloads`.  This is the share.  I'm not really sure what the dkms package is, but I found it in an [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/465301/375885).

Comment: I'm also not sure why it's called `sf_...`

Answer (score 0):

The shared folder is not mounted usually - even if you check "auto-mount". I was confused too.

Run on the guest

```
sudo mkdir /media/shared/downloads # there was bug here
sudo mount download /media/shared/downloads -t vboxfs    # or vboxsf
```

and it should be mounted..

You may need VirtualBox Client Additions installed on the guest machine, but I've found them present in some recent distributions.

If you need to change visible UID of the files mounts, add `-o uid=1000,gid=1000` as additional mount option.

UPDATE: The `vboxsf.ko` kernel module is present in `linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic` package on my Ubuntu 16.04.1 (which I used for testing). But it's possible that the file is not present on your VM.

See result:

```
dpkg  -S /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxsf/vboxsf.ko
linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic: /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxsf/vboxsf.ko
```

Comment: I've also found another answer on "automount doesn't work as expected" on [askUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/252865), but I've personally never tried that approach and can't confirm it works.

Comment: 1. `mount point /media/shared/downloads does not exist`, so I changed it to `/media/shared` (the folder you had me create).
2. `unknown filesystem type 'vboxfs'` (same with vboxsf)